# Body-parser not working with POST-MAN form data

Tags: node.js, express

I try to send image, some text in form data  and I try to `console.log(req.body)` It's always `return {}` I've read many topic about this

here is my route/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.route('/').post(AdminController.list);
```

I tryo to add urlencoded but it still not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bodyParser` cannot handle `multipart/form-data`

Try Multer, [From official docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer):

> Multer is a node.js middleware for handling multipart/form-data, which
>   is primarily used for uploading files. It is written on top of busboy
>   for maximum efficiency
>
> Multer adds a body object and a file or files object to the request
>   object. The body object contains the values of the text fields of the
>   form, the file or files object contains the files uploaded via the
>   form.

See a working example:

```
const Multer = require('multer');
const multer = Multer({
    storage: Multer.memoryStorage(),
    limits: {
        fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 // no larger than 5mb, you can change as needed.
    }
});

app.post('/upload', multer.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
    fs.createWriteStream('./uploads/' + req.file.originalname)
    var fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(req.file.originalname);
    fileWriteStream.on('finish', () => {
        console.log('file saved successfully');
        res.send({ message: 'file saved successfully' })
    })
    fileWriteStream.end(req.file.buffer)
})
```

Comment: well, what if I send description with image . how can I get req.body.description  by ?using form-data

Comment: @Ach you can get it from req.body which will contain the text fields, if there were any

Comment: Can you show me where Should I console.log(req.body)

Comment: @Ach it's there in the answer. see 2nd line in app.post

Comment: thanks  works now . So . if i've image I must use multer to use it with form-data else I can use bodyPaser with json data . =]